# ng-pattern for only number with no decimal

Tags: angularjs

Need ng-pattern for restricting entry of decimal in input type number.I have used 
***ng-pattern="/^[0-9]$/"*** 
to get the result but its not showing error on 1.0,2.0,3.0 etc.
Example:

```
2.0 = fail
2 = pass
3.0=fail
3=pass

<div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-7">

<input type="number"  min="0" class="form-control" id="equalizingFactor" 
 name="equalizingFactor" ng-model="flatVariable.equalizingFactor" 
 itle="Equalizing Factor" ng-maxlength="3" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]$/" 
 message="The field should contain only numbers with no decimal places"
 ng-readonly="flatVariable.pgmInd30"/>

</div>
```

Should only have numbers no decimals included.

Comment: Pls show us what you've tried so far

Comment: ng-pattern="/^[0-9]$/" i have used this ng-pattern .

Comment: Please show the sample code which you've tried instead of asking as a requirement.

Comment: look at [this working example](http://jsfiddle.net/KGd8K/)

Comment: Your code works fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/TYhHmI4D33gJyzGXTzX9?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These should work fine:

```
ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/"  // 0 or more numbers

ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+$/"  // 1 or more numbers

ng-pattern="/^\d*$/"     // 0 or more numbers

ng-pattern="/^\d+$/"     // 1 or more numbers
```